# How to put a parameter with quote string in PigLatin?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, apache-pig

I have a problem in PigLatin

I have a piece of Pig code which will invoke a string with quote

```
data = LOAD '$data' AS (...);
a = some_macro(data,'-9999 AS KEY');
```

the macro is like this:

```
DEFINE some_macro(data, string) RETURNS results {
    grp = GROUP $data ALL;
    $result = FOREACH grp {
        //...logic and logics
        GENERATE $string, //...other fields
        ...;
    }
}
```

for the string "-9999 AS KEY", it seems the Pig 0.10 can't work, then I try "'-9999' AS KEY", it can't work again.

So anyone has a solution for that? I just want a flexible KEY name.

Answer (score 2):

Please try `GENERATE '$string', //...other logic`, i.e. put the `$string` in single quotes. I could only test with pig 0.9.1 but it works for me.

`some_macro(data,'-9999 AS KEY');` with simple quotes is correct.

This won't work with single quotes in you string, however.

Comment: ok, but the logic is quite complex, so I believe it is impossible to use un-nest FOREACH...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a quoted string, first modify your script as Fred described and use the Unicode equivalent of the quotation mark when passing the parameter, e.g:

```
a = some_macro(data,'\\u0022-9999 AS KEY\\u0022'); // "-9999 AS KEY"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I give up, the Pig parser engine can't accept a single quota or a minus '-' in the macro.

There one solution for me, use the driver code to replace some stub in pig files.

actually the Pig should do it like that, but I don't know why it do not in macro.